# why Network programs store IP addresses in the IP address structure

Tags: c, sockets, ip

I'm a beginner in C, my textbooks cover some network programming in C, and states that Network programs store IP addresses in the IP address structure

```
/* Internet address structure */
struct in_addr {
unsigned int s_addr; /* Network byte order (big-endian) */
};
```

I'm confused, can't we just store a 32 bit integer?

Answer (score 1):

`in_addr` represents an IPv4 address, which can indeed fit in a 32bit integer.

But, there are other types of socket addresses that cannot, such as IPv6 addresses.

Each type of socket address uses its own struct type:

- `in_addr` for IPv4
- `in6_addr` for IPv6
- `char[]` for UNIX paths
- etc

Usually wrapped inside a corresponding `sockaddr` struct:

- `sockaddr_in` for IPv4
- `sockaddr_in6` for IPv6
- `sockaddr_un` for UNIX
- etc

Which is what you use with socket APIs like `bind()`, `connect()`, `accept()`, `sendto()`, `recvfrom()`, etc.

Very rarely would you ever need to use something like `in_addr` directly by itself.  Typically you would use it in conjunction with an API that requires an IPv4 address to be passed via the `in_addr` struct.